# Import csv to cart

Tags: commerce, importing-exporting

Is there a way to import from a cvs (or similar) to the cart?
The csv could be very simple: sku and quantity.
I'm using Drupal 7 with commerce.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there are no modules that implement this. You might be able to get feeds working if there were some tampers added that were able to create an order and associate it with the information that was coming in (e.g. you're creating line items). But that's just a guess. You'll need to implement something custom for this.